Is it possible to add custom data in meta in papertrail only in the 'create' event
 has_paper_trail meta:{
    object: 'custom_data'
  }

this is my code need to have a condition where we add meta only in case of create
i tried this
  has_paper_trail meta: {
    object: ->{ instance.new_record? ? 'custom_data' : nil }
  }

and
 has_paper_trail on: [:create] meta:{
    object: 'custom_data'
  }

but its not working
need to add this metadata only in case of create event and work normally for update and destroy

Hi there is a way to do this only for create event. Please check this out and let me know.
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail meta: { object: 'custom_data' }, if: :new_record?
end


undefined method `call' for :will_save_new_record? getting this error

@HarishKumar Remove method and Try this - has_paper_trail meta: { object: 'custom_data' }, if: :new_record?

achieved this with this code 'has_paper_trail on: [:create], meta: { object: "custom_data" }' but i need normal flow incase of update and destroy

I am assuming you are new here, you need to clarify what you required in your question instead of comments @HarishKumar

I think the solution you tried originally was quite close. The problem with calling .new_record? is that by the time we call it the object has already been saved to the database and so it returns false.
There is another method we can make use of here however, and it's previously_new_record?. This method returns true if the object was just created. More info in the docs.
This is an example that may work for you:
  has_paper_trail meta: {
    object: ->(post) do
      post.previously_new_record? ? 'custom_data' : nil
    end
  }


EDIT
Just spotted you're using Rails 3 and previously_new_record? won't be available for you :(
It's a bit awkward, but something like this may work:
  has_paper_trail

  after_create :add_create_metadata

  private

  def add_create_metadata
    self.versions.last.update(meta: 'custom_data')
  end

This means you're doing an extra write to the database, which may or may not be appropriate for you.
